# Return value for function containing jQuery $.post() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, return-value

I understand that AJAX is asynchronous, and all that. But I have the following code:

```
function doesUsernameExist(element)
{
    // Check via AJAX (POST) if username already exists in the database
    var funcReturned = null;
    $.post(
        '_ajax_checkexist.php',
        {
            var: 'username',
            value: element.value
        },
        function(data) {
            funcReturned = (data.toLowerCase() == 'exists');
        },
        'data'
    );
    return funcReturned;
}
```

I understand **why** the function isn't returning a value properly, but what can I use as a workaround? This is for the Validity plugin, which requires a boolean returned by the *doesUsernameExist* function. I can't do the usual workaround of having the $.post function alter some HTML element. It needs to return true/false to *doesUsernameExist*.

What kind of workaround can I use? I'm stumped by this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for validation purposes you will find that the [jquery.validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) and its [`remote rule`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote) are perfectly adapted for what you are trying to achieve.

So, instead of writing `doesUsernameExist` functions and worrying about *asynchronousness* of AJAX and how to return values you will write validation rules for your form (which in fact is the final goal of the exercise => focus on the business and leave the plumbing to plugins):

```
$('#id_of_some_form').validate({
    rules: {
        password: {
            required: true
        },
        username: { 
            remote: '_ajax_checkexist.php'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This actually looks perfect. No idea how I missed it while looking for validation plugins. Thanks!

Comment: @TerranRich, not only this *looks* perfect. It **is** perfect and kind of *the* reference jquery plugin in terms of validation. Even Microsoft are now shipping it as part of their ASP.NET MVC framework.

Answer (score 13):

You could return a value if the call is synchronous. Here you have an example:

**Solution for synchronous mode:**

```
function doesUsernameExist(element)
{
    // Check via AJAX (POST) if username already exists in the database
    var funcReturned = null;
    $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
    $.post(
        '_ajax_checkexist.php',
        {
            var: 'username',
            value: element.value
        },
        function(data) {
            funcReturned = (data.toLowerCase() == 'exists');
        },
        'data'
    );
    $.ajaxSetup({async: true});
    return funcReturned;
}
```

The problem with your code, is that while the `$.post` is executing, the function continues it's execution (that's asynchronous), so will return `null` before your `$.post` ended.

**Solution for asynchronous mode:**
Using an asyncrhonous call, you cannot return a value, but can call callbacks or execute code just there. This could be an async solution:

```
function doesUsernameExist(element)
{    
    var funcReturned = null;
    $.post( //This post is asynchronous
        '_ajax_checkexist.php',
        {
            var: 'username',
            value: element.value
        },
        function(data) {
            funcReturned = (data.toLowerCase() == 'exists');
            userExistanceCallback(funcReturned);
        },
        'data'
    );
    //We don't return anything
}

function userExistanceCallback(funcReturned){
   if(funcReturned == true)
       alert("User exists!!");
   else
       alert("User does not exist!!");
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Ya, the answer is useful bot not in here