# Read and write JSON file for mobile app

Tags: html, cordova, ember.js, cross-domain, local-storage

I am working on a mobile app. Since I wanted a solution that would work on multiple platforms, I started with `Cordova`. As I have much data to handle and many views, I decided to use `Ember`.

I need to use three different JSON datasets that are updated rather frequently in the database. To enable the mobile app to work offline, I will have to store the JSON data, as well as update them when the database is changed.

**Questions**

1. How can I retrieve JSON from another server(CORS blocked)?
2. How can the retrieved JSON be saved on device? [`HTML5 LocalStorage`(preferred) or FileAPI]
3. How to read JSON file and send data as model to templates? (I guess `Ember.$.getJSON` can do this)

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

**Update 1**

1. Since I ran into many issues using `Ember-data`, I am not using it in my app.
2. Found this link for cross-domain with [ajax](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-data-and-cors/3690/2)

**Update 2**

CORS can be solved only by `JSONP` or by setting `ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN` in the reponse of the server(I tried many other solutions, and failed)

Since the api is in my server, I did the latter.

For **2** and **3**, I think I could use [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848739/using-ajax-to-return-a-json-object)

Comment: Try using native HTTP via phonegap plugin. It should help to get pass the CORS limitation. https://github.com/bperin/HttpRequest

Comment: @blessenm The above plugin requires Android PhoneGap, the link to which is broken. Besides i was looking for a solution for at least android and iOS.

Comment: The above phonegap plugin was just an example to point u to a direction. AKAIK for servers that are CORS blocked, u either got jsonp or native http as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found out :

1. **JSON data from a server in different domain**
   You cannot read `JSON` data from a server in another domain. This is due to the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) implemented in browsers. A browser will retrieve your `JSON` but will not allow you access to the same. There are two solutions(AFAIK) to this problem :

   - **Using JSONP** - I'm not going into the details, but there are many links available for this.
   - **Allow CORS from server** - When the server sends JSONified data, you can add additional headers for `ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN`. After retrieving the JSON from server, the browser checks for this header to either block or allow `CORS`. I used some decorators for adding `crossdomain` headers and then my data was successfully read in the browser.
2. **Saving the json data**
   `HTML5` makes everything easier. In your javascript, you just have to use :

   ```
   localStorage["application.state.data"] = JSON.stringify(json);
   ```

   or

   ```
   localStorage.setItem("application.state.data", JSON.stringify(json));
   ```
3. **Retrieve works just the same**

   ```
   var data = JSON.parse(localStorage["application.state.data"]);
   ```

   or

   ```
   var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("application.state.data"));
   ```